# How do i get the primary key back when I update a record into a table in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

As we knows, If update a record, we will get boolean value back, but if I want get primary key id back. How should I write the querybuilder?

```
$dq = $this->repository->createQueryBuilder('u');
$query = $dq->update()
    ->set('u.isLocked', $dq->expr()->literal(true))
    ->where('u.token = :token and u.isDeleted = :isDeleted')
    ->setParameter('isDeleted', false)
    ->setParameter('token', $token)
    ->getQuery();

return $this->execute($query);
```

Comment: when you are updating the  record just return the primary key of the row if update successfull or false if update fails.

Comment: I want it get false back if update fails and get primary key back if update success.How should i write the querybuilder?

Comment: can you please post your full code

Comment: ok ,I post my code in my question now.

Comment: if($this->execute($query)) {
 return $id;
} else {
  return false;
}

Comment: I am sorry ,please see my new post code. I want to get id back in this stuation.

Comment: may be you need to write another query.I am not sure.

Comment: Yep.  You will need to do a query specifically for the id's of the records to be updated.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I do not know how to write the code to get primary key back , do you have good ideas?